# Change global variable and get changed value from another .php file

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm trying to change background color with button and I can do this, but if I change the page I couldn't get the changed value of variable. Maybe this is a stupid way to do this; I don't know, but I hope it is not.

home-featured-fullwidth.php:

```
<?php
global $arka;
$arka = 'wall2';
$button = 'button2';

if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
    $arka = "wall";
    $button = 'button1';
}
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    $arka = "wall2";
    $button = 'button2';
}

echo '<div class="home-featured-full ' . $arka . '">';?>
// codes and close </div>

<form class="padding" method="POST" action=''>
    <?php echo '<input id="iki" type="submit" name="' . $button . '"  value="Change BackGround">'; ?>
</form>
```

single-video-fullwidth.php:

```
<?php 
echo '<div class="' . $arka . ' full-width-video-layout">' ?>codes and close </div>
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol and the PHP implementation does not try to work around this. This means, that global variables are by design global only to the single request.

In short words: A variable from one PHP request will typically not be available in another PHP request.

Since your scenario is very common, the construct of `sessions` exist, which allow you to store a variable "in the session" and retrieve it at a later request. Read up on PHP sessions, they are easy to use and mostly good enough for single-server use.

Comment: what ever i tried i get an error : 
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\WT-NMP\WWW\wp-includes\

Comment: Reading up in sessions will give you the information, that `session_start()` must come before the absolutely first output - this includes everything, also whitespace, coming before the `<?php`

Comment: if possible can you give me an example. I think session is already started  and i tried to use  `$_SESSION['mesaj']=$arka;
if (isset($_SESSION['mesaj'])) {
$button='button2';
}` so session is exist. but still i can not get it from another php using `$_SESSION['mesaj']`

Comment: The php documentation at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php has a perfectly readable example!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with this:

```
<? PHP session_start();

echo "this is the first file";

$_SESSION['global'] = "From the first file";

?>
```

Create other file with this:

```
<? PHP session_start();

echo "this is the second file";

if(@isset($_SESSION['global'])){
    echo $_SESSION['global'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I can not use `session_start()` i wrote the error above. I try without `session_start()` it did not work. no value was send from first.php to second.php file

Comment: session_start most be the first sentence, check in the example <? PHP session_start(); you get the warning because is not the first sentence.

Comment: try use @session_start();  if really the session is started